# jpa jpql Query on OneToMany relation

Tags: java, jpa, entity, jpql

i have two Entity objects

object 1

```
@Entity
MyInfo
String key;
String eMail;
String status;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="myInfo")
private List<MyInfoRequest>  myInfoRequests;
```

object 2

```
@Entity
MyInfoRequest
String key;
String dataA;
String dataB;
String dataC;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="KEY")
MyInfo myInfo;
```

i try to  createQuery (JPQL) with  EntityManager

that wil give me all MyInfo with status="1" and myInfoRequest.dataA="BIG"
but what i get is all myInfoRequest.dataA="BIG" and MyInfo with same info
(i get the result as MyInfo object list  of course)

this what i try

```
SELECT x from MyInfo x,MyInfoRequest b where b.dataA=:dataA AND x.status=:status
```

Im using jpa 1.0.
and OpenJPA 1.2.1

Comment: Try below query and see what this returns -->select x from MyInfo x left join fetch x.myInfoRequests b where x.status=:status and b.dataA=:dataA

Comment: openjpa dont like it.. 
this what it get: 
<openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Encountered "b" at character 63, but expected: [",", ".", "GROUP", "HAVING", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", "ORDER", "WHERE", <EOF>].

Comment: Do you get same error with (Do not set parameter) --> select x from MyInfo x left join fetch x.myInfoRequests b where x.status=1 and b.dataA='BIG'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
...
String qlString = "SELECT x "
                + "FROM MyInfo x JOIN x.myInfoRequests b "
                + "WHERE x.status = :status AND b.dataA = :dataA";
List<MyInfo> result = em.createQuery(qlString)
                        .setParameter("status", "1")
                        .setParameter("dataA", "BIG")
                        .getResultList();
```